# Know What UINavigationController the User is Inside UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` that has 3 UINavigationControllers in my AppDelegate and I want to know how to determine the active `UINavigationController` where the user is. How can I determine this?

Comment: What about `[yourTabBarController selectedViewController]`?

Comment: Will it work even if it's a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Yes, `selectedViewController` returns the currently displayed navigation controller. Why do you think that is does not work? What result do you get?

Comment: My plan is to display a custom notification view below my navigation controller nav bar and it's not showing in the correct place I want to. It's displaying in my nav bar where it's blocking my app logo which should not be.

Comment: I even tried yourTabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController.view and it's not working too.

Comment: Perhaps you have to go to the view *presented* by the navigation controller, something like `[[yourTabBarController selectedViewController] topViewController]`.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work either. Your exact code doesn't work as it's giving me an error. I did tried yourTabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController.topViewController.view yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `[(UINavigationController *)[yourTabBarController selectedViewController] topViewController]`.

Answer (score 1):

`UITabBarController` has a property called `selectedViewController`. Just check this for the appropriate value (e.g. by checking its class or a tag of its main view).

Comment: Thanks. Checking this out.

Comment: It doesn't since I have a UINavigationController inside my UITabBarControllers. It does work if I have a UIViewController only.

Comment: So identify the nav controller, or its `topViewController`. Same concept.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out on my own.

I just used this code to make my code work. It may seem a bit far from my original question but this made it to work as I just simply want to display my custom notification view on my current view.

```
if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
{
    [self displayNotificationWhenOnline:self.navController1.visibleViewController.view];
}
else if (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex == 1)
{
    [self displayNotificationWhenOnline:self.navController2.visibleViewController.view];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get perticuler view controller using this code,

```
[(UINavigationController*)[[(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate] tabBarController] selectedViewController]visibleViewController]
```

Comment: That the same as the above, `selectedViewController`.